# Dockerfile: RUN command with special parameters

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to run bash commands with special parameters like $_ inside the Dockerfile. 
I tried the following example but it seems to be not working. If I execute the same command in the bash directly, it works like a charm. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$ RUN mkdir /foo && cd $_ && pwd
```

Comment: Can you try with `RUN bash -c 'mkdir /foo && cd $_ && pwd'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on shell in base container. ubuntu is using dash for example, changing default shell to bash is helping to get result which you expect:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN mkdir /foo && cd $_ && pwd
```

result:

```
docker build --rm .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> d0955f21bf24
Step 1 : RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c90ef9fd9710
Step 2 : RUN mkdir /foo && cd $_ && pwd
 ---> Running in 8e1d943a6b60
/foo
 ---> 1871918ee02c
Removing intermediate container 8e1d943a6b60
Successfully built 1871918ee02c
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know that debian like distros using a different shell implementation. Replacing the syslink is solving my requirement. Do you know if there is an Dash equivalent of the  $_ parameter?

Comment: dash setting _ variable only when it is interactive, I don't know a way to use $_ in non-interactive dash session.